# Generate a string format based on fixed length and numeric units on each increment

Tags: sql-server

I had to write a SP to generate a string with the combination of Country (7 chars) + Province (1 char) + numeric number starts from 01. for eg: JAMAICAK01
where JAMAICA (Country) , K (Province) and 01 is the numeric number that gets incremented by 1 for each transaction.

The issue I have here is the generated string length max is 10, can be lesser than 10 but not >10.

It should be handled in a way with certain rules like

1. the combination don't exist
2. When the numeric unit changes from tens to hundreds making the string 
   length >10, I need to remove the right chars for eg JAMAICAKKK10 to 
   JAMAICAK10 from the right to make the total max length 10.

In my code below I tried to check if the combination exists and I get the max of it and do the numeric increment from the last one. think it can be done in a better way.

```
       Declare @Province char(2)
       Declare @Country varchar(10)
       declare @CounProv varchar(10)
       Declare @SimilarCounPRov varchar(max) = '';
       declare @FinalString nvarchar(12)
       declare @s varchar(50)
       declare @s1 varchar(50)
       declare @s2 varchar(50)

       Set @Province = LEFT('KINGSTON', 1)           
       Set @Country = LEFT('JAMAICA', 7)   

       Set @CounProv = @Country+@Province

       Select @SimilarCounPRov = MAX(field1) from dbo.table where field1  
       LIKE '%JAMAICAK%' 

       if @SimilarCounPRov IS NOT NULL 
   BEGIN
   Set @s = (select fn_AlphaOnly('%JAMAICAK99%')) -- returns JAMAICAK

   Set @s1 = (select fn_NumericOnly('%JAMAICAK99%'))  -- returns 199

   set @s2= @s1 +1   -- increment by 1

   if len(@FinalString) > 10
      ---- 
       need help here----`
```

Comment: "remove the right chars for eg" does not show valid result for Seq#.  Your result shows JAMAICA 7 char and K 1 char and Seq# 2 digits, but not 100 or 101,...
Declare-s for Country and Province are too long.
It seems like it is time to re-design the table so that Country, Province, and SeqNum each have their own separate normalized columns, which are later formatted as 10 char only when displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understood all your requirements but if you need to generate strings like : JAMAICAK1,JAMAICAK2,...JAMAICAK10...,JAMAICAK11,...JAMAICA100,JAMAICA101,...JAMAIC1000,JAMAIC1001...

You can try to exploit this piece of code :

```
Declare @Province char(2)
Declare @Country varchar(10)
Declare @CounProv varchar(10)
Declare @value int 
Declare @str_value VARCHAR(100) 

Set @Province   = LEFT('KINGSTON', 1)           
Set @Country    = LEFT('JAMAICA', 7)   
Set @value      = 999999
Set @CounProv   = @Country+@Province
Set @str_value  = (select CAST(@value AS varchar(100)))

select LEFT(@CounProv,10-LEN(@str_value))+@str_value
```

Tell me if it helps.